# c++ programming, login attempt, failing while loop

Tags: c++, file, authentication, while-loop

I'm using this code, and it's all working, it's accepting or declining the correct/incorrect username and password combinations like it should be, but either way it shows "Login failed" and I can't work out why.. So when it's correct it comes up 
"Login successful
Login failed" or the other way around depending on which combination it is.

I just want to make it so that it shows only the appropriate "successful" or "failed". 
Any help would be very much appreciated please?

```
include iostream
include fstream
include string
include sstream


using namespace std;

int fail = 3;
string user, pass, _user, _pass;

int main()
{
    string line = " ";
    ifstream readfile("user.dat");

    cout << "\nEnter Username: ";
    cin >> user;
    cout << "\nEnter Password: ";
    cin >> pass;
while (getline(readfile, line))
    {
        stringstream iss(line);
        iss>> _user >> _pass;

        if (user == _user && pass == _pass)
            cout << "\nLogin successful";
        else
            cout << "\nLogin failed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have multiple lines in the data file? Then you will loop over *all* of them, comparing the entered username and password with all the entries.

What you should do instead is to check the username first, and if it doesn't match continue looping. If there is a username match, *then* you check the password, and no matter if the password match or not you break out of the loop (no use in continuing the loop when you already found your username in the file).

You might also want to keep a boolean variable, initialized to false, to be set if the passwords match, so you can check that after the loop.

---

Some pseudo-code:

```
while (get next line)
{
    parse line into user and password
    if (user from file is equal to entered username)
    {
        check password
        break out of loop
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I have 7 lines. I really don't understand much at all of what you've said here, I'm only rather new to this and haven't done much outside int. thanks though.

Comment: @chrystle Think about what would happen if the correct user/password pair is in the second line of the file. Then the loop will first print out `"Login failed"` once, then in the second iteration of the loop it would print `"Login successful"`, and in all other five iteration it would again print `"Login failed"`.

Comment: @chrystle Also modified my answer to add some pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code as follows:

```
while (getline(readfile, line))
{
        stringstream iss(line);
        iss>> _user >> _pass;

        if (user == _user && pass == _pass)
        { // 1
            cout << "\nLogin successful";
            break; // do not read another line in case of success
        } // 3
        else
            cout << "\nLogin failed";
    }
}
```

Otherwise, after a successfull authentication, you read again from the input and validate again (you probably read a blank string - or similar).

Comment: This works for the first line, it doesn't show any others, but if I enter any of the others, eg. the 5th line, it shows 
"Login failed
Login failed
Login failed
Login failed
Login successful"?

Answer (score -1):

Don't compare strings using == , use strmcp(string s1, string s2)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Which in C++ will do the same as the equality operator between two `std::string` objects.